# Use API key with googleapis androidpublisher

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm building a server locally with NPM to get information from google play publisher.
I'm trying to user API key but I'm unable to connect.
const publish = google.androidpublisher({
version: 'v3',
auth: '****'
});
From looking in the internet I'm seeing that I need to use OAuth2.
The problem is that I want this as a service and only a server side without user interaction.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must use Service Account Credentials as outlined [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-account-credentials)